# How can I make a menubar fixed on the top while scrolling

Tags: html, css, menubar, css-position

I'd like to make a menubar, which is fixed on the top of the page while scrolling. Something like the top menu in Facebook.

Also, I want a div holding the logo float at the left of menubar, and a nav float at the right of the menubar.

Comment: by giving position fixed

Comment: don't ask any ready made code on StackOverflow, first try on your way and if you have an error then paste your code on StackOverflow or ask a error for your menubar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should get you started

```
 <div class="menuBar">
        <img class="logo" src="logo.jpg"/>
        <div class="nav"> 
            <ul>
                <li>Menu1</li>
                <li>Menu 2</li>
                <li>Menu 3</li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>



body{
    margin-top:50px;}
.menuBar{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    }
.logo{
    float:left;
    }
.nav{
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;}
.nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    }
```

Comment: This code does not answer the question. It does not remain fixed while scrolling. In the very least you would need to use `position:fixed`. I have no idea why this has any upvotes, and why it's the accepted answer, other than "it's just some code to get you started".

Answer (score 14):

```
 #header {
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        background-color:#FFF;
    }

    #content {
        position:static;
        margin-top:100px;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

to set a div at position fixed you can use

```
position:fixed
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:50px; /* change me */
```

Answer (score 3):

The `postition:absolute;` tag positions the element relative to it's immediate parent.
I noticed that even in the examples, there isn't room for scrolling, and when i tried it out, it didn't work.
Therefore, to pull off the facebook floating menu, the `position:fixed;` tag should be used instead. It displaces/keeps the element at the given/specified location, and the rest of the page can scroll smoothly - even with the responsive ones.

Please see [CSS postion attribute documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) when you can :)

Comment: Yes that was answer in my mind ( if he  means  fixed by the meaning), but if he means fixed by term so the answer should be position:fixed