# menubar at the top (Div element) remains while you scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, menubar

I'm making a simple (test)-website and I want to add a menubar (at the top of the website) that stays on the same place when you scroll down instead of it's disappears. I know I need jQuery and probably also JavaScript. Its not like a sliding menu, it's like stackoverflow has on the right side of the website when you want to post a question -> but now I want it on de top with an menubar.

How can I make this sort of menu bar?

thanks for responds,

Niels.

Comment: If it never ever moves, this is a CSS question. Read about the position property.

Comment: If my answer helped I'd love it if you would mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

You only need CSS. You merely have to give it a fixed position:

```
#topBar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
```

That will scroll with the page. See also [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449272/how-can-i-make-a-menubar-fixed-on-the-top-while-scrolling?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Is this effect that you want? 
http://www.sutanaryan.com/Tutorials/fixed-menu-when-scrolling-page-with-CSS-and-jQuery/