# Offsetting link within same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu bar at the top that has links as below:

```
<a href="#1">Football</a>
<a href="#2">Cricket</a>
<a href="#3">Rugby</a>
<a href="#4">Tennis</a>
```

I have a fixed menu bar that is 50px in height. When the links are clicked, the headings are hidden behind the fixed menu bar. Is it possible to have the headings be displayed 50px lower (so they can show) when its corresponding link is clicked.

html:

```
<h2 class="menuheading" id="1">Football</h2>
...
<h2 class="menuheading" id="2">Cricket</h2>
...
<h2 class="menuheading" id="3">Rugby</h2>
...
<h2 class="menuheading" id="4">Tennis</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may apply always a `padding-top/margin-top` to your headings or (in modern browser) only when they are targetted — as you asked, e.g.

```
h2:target {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Further information about `:target` pseudoclass on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget)

Comment: As you answered first, you get the best answer! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS style for `menuheading`

```
.menuheading {
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible duplicate of this... [How can I make a menubar fixed on the top while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449272/how-can-i-make-a-menubar-fixed-on-the-top-while-scrolling)

What happens is the body tag is loaded at the top of the page by default, so all you need to do is put

```
body {margin-top:50px;} /* Same height as the menu bar */
```

it goes into more detail on the attached question link.

Comment: no, this won't solve the problem because headings will be always covered. Maybe could be useful for the first heading only