# How do I make text scroll with me?

Tags: html, css, animation, scroll, menu

I'm having trouble finding out how to do this: How do I make my menu bar scroll with me as I scroll down the page? Is it possible, if so, how? here is my code for my menu bar:

```
<aside>
                <code>

                    <p class="menu"><a class="menu" href="home.html">Home</a></p>
                    <BR>
                    <p class="menu"><a class="menu" href="#">About</a></p>
                    <BR>
                    <p class="menu"><a class="menu" href="#">Freelance</a></p>
                    <BR>
                    <p class="menu"><a class="menu" href="#">Buy</a></p>
                    <BR>
                    <p class="menu"><a class="menu" href="#">Contact</a></p>

                </code>
            </aside>
```

Please help or send me to sources that will help!

Comment: I don't think anybody will be able to answer it with the current information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the style of that menu with `position: fixed` and add `z-index: 999999999;` to make sure its always on top of the display.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

```
<ul id=menu>
<li><a href="#L384">Section 1</a>
<li><a href="#details">Section 2</a>
<li><a href="#FAQ">Section 3</a>
</ul>
```

Css

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 8em;
  margin-top: -2.5em;
}
```

visit this site for demo: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus.en.html

- [Another example of Top Fixed Menu Bar On Scroll](http://fellowtuts.com/html-css/top-fixed-menu-bar-on-scroll-with-css-jquery-less-code/)
- [Menu bar fixed on top while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449272/how-can-i-make-a-menubar-fixed-on-the-top-while-scrolling)